# Unable to remove openmediavault package due to postrm script error

Tags: package-management, dpkg

Managed to set up SABnzb, Sickbeard and Couch Potato and all working nicely

I have a problem with Ubuntu 12.04 server. When trying to upgrade or install any package it errors and fails as below

```
Now updating apache2-utils ..
Installing package(s) with command apt-get -y install apache2-utils ..
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...

The following packages will be REMOVED:
  openmediavault-omvextrasorg

The following packages will be upgraded:
  apache2-utils
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/91.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 337 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 120507 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing openmediavault-omvextrasorg ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openmediavault-omvextrasorg.postrm: 23: .: Can't open /etc/default/openmediavault
dpkg: error processing openmediavault-omvextrasorg (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openmediavault-omvextrasorg
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
.. install failed!

No packages were installed. Check the messages above for the cause of the error.
<-  Return to package list
```

(This is from Webmin but same result if using Putty or direct on machine)

I have an HP Microserver N54L with 8Gig RAM

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

1. Precise fix: `touch /etc/default/openmediavault` and try again. There may be other problems you need to fix.
2. Nuke it from orbit: `rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/openmediavault-omvextrasorg.postrm`

I have found that there are many .deb pre/post scripts that are written with assumptions that may not be true. My favorite one is the prerm script that assumes the daemon is still running and causes apt-get to fail when it isn't.

Edit: Looking at https://github.com/OpenMediaVault-Plugin-Developers/openmediavault-omvextrasorg/blob/master/debian/postrm I'm guessing (1) will fail. Using (2) you may need to run these commands:

```
/bin/rm -f /etc/apt/preferences.d/99omv-extras-org*
/bin/rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/omv-extras-org-*.list
```

Comment: Wow I don't know what line fixed it but I ran them all and didn't see anything happen. All the pending updates have installed now so thanks very muck. I had already tried all the commands I could find by Googling and nothing worked. Was about to blitz it and start again from scratch. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score -1):

I have also been served, I have also been served, just need to remove the package apt-get --force-yes remove openmediavault-omvextrasorg